# using another c# class from a c# class

Tags: c#, asp.net

i've a gallery.aspx with code behind (this is not a project, only have two files), i want to use another c# class called CFileInfo at same directory.

i use using CFileInfo; in gallery.cs but it is not work.

```
    CFileInfo oDetailedFileInfo = new CFileInfo(sFileName);
```

The above code is also not work. The CFileInfo looks like

```
public class CFileInfo
    {
...
    }
```

There is no namespace created.

How can i use CFileInfo.cs in gallery.cs?

Comment: is your gallery class static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your class and with name space

```
 namespace FileObjects
    {

        public   class CFileInfo
        {
             public CFileInfo() { }

            //Add your functions here
        }

    }
```

Now you call this in gallyer.aspx

```
**using FileOBjects;**
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class gallery : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             CFileInfo oDetailedFileInfo = new CFileInfo(sFileName);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: @hkinterview Don't add the asterick's before and after the using statement

Comment: it is to highlight that we are using namespace

Comment: I understood it. The comment is for the OP, as a joke

Comment: hahaha still @hkinterview didnt reply which answer is working for him

Comment: not work ...... dont' know why, i have a similar code using a Node.cs but it works

Comment: If i turn the directory into web application in IIS, it works, but is it a must? Because the code may be used in a server which i can't access the IIS

Comment: can you show screen shot of your  visual studio having these classes added

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `CFileInfo.cs` into App_Code directory. I'm pretty sure that VS compiler issues warning about this.

Comment: i've tried,  The type or namespace name 'CFileInfo' could not be found

Comment: And do you compile/deploy the whole site with VS?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, C# has a global (or unnamed) namespace - you can use global:: to access your class::

```
using myCFileInfo = global::CFileInfo;
```